# How can I prevent MBP shocks without original three prong extender?

Tags: hardware, power

I no longer have the original three prong extension cord for my MBP, and am experiencing the shock issue described by many other users.

I purchased a three prong travel plug and tried that, but it did not solve the problem.

Is there anything else I can do to solve the problem? I don't have access to an Apple Store, and can't modify the electrical outlets (if there is a grounding problem, for example).

Thanks.